# How do I use variables while making a new color in java

Tags: java

I am in a programming class and we are making a class to get input from the user for making an ellipse (the major axis the minor axis and the hard part color). What I want to do is have the user enter in the rbg values and make a custom color to fill the ellipse. In the main class I have all the input done through a JOptionPane window and parsed into double values and I am displaying the ellipse in a JFrame.

```
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the major Axis of your Ellipse: ");
    int majAxis = Integer.parseInt(input);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Minor Axis of your Ellipse:");
    int minAxis = Integer.parseInt(input);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the red value in the RBG of your color:");
    double red = Double.parseDouble(input);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the blue value in the RBG of your color:");
    double blue = Double.parseDouble(input);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the green value in the RBG of your color:");
    double green = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Then i have it passed through a constructor to the other class:

```
    Ellipse component = new Ellipse(majAxis, minAxis, red, blue, green);
```

then in the other class I have the data transferred from a constructor to instance variable then into the new color constructor.

```
public Ellipse(int maj, int min, double red1, double blue1, double green1)
{
    major = maj;
    minor = min;
    red = red1;
    blue = blue1;
    green = green1;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //sets up access to graphics
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    Color custom = new Color(red, blue, green);          //this is where i get an error saying the variable is undefined.

    Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double((this.getWidth()-major) / 2,(this.getHeight()-minor) / 2,major,minor);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(e);
}
private int major;
private int minor;
private double red;
private double blue;
private double green;
```

I need to be able to use the variables and i don't know why it isn't working. So can please get some help of suggestions on how to do this. i don't want to use if statements and preset colors so this is my only option.

Comment: This ought to work, I'm not sure why it doesn't

Comment: Is the paintComponent method part of the Ellipse class?

Comment: Could we see the whole Ellipse class

Answer (score 2):

First, you should pass

```
Color custom = new Color(red, green, blue);  // in this order: R G B
```

Second, your variables `red`, `green` and `blue` actually are not defined. You should assign them a value BEFORE you call the `new Color(r, g, b)`.

Third, the constructor of class Color accepts parameters of types `int` (0..255) or `float` (0..1). So may be you should replace `double red, green, blue` with a `float red, green, blue`.